# Embed UI App in Windows IoT

Tags: windows-iot, performance

I developed a foreground app (UI app) for RPI3 on windows IoT core (version 1709: Fall creators update). also I made my app as start-up app. I want to access the app immediately after turning the device on. I have two problems now:

1. I want to remove windows logon screen. (or remove windows logo at least)
2. The start up time is very long (about 2 minutes!) from turning on till launching my app. I want to reduce it as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to remove the Windows Logo is to be part of the OEM or Enterprise program that Microsoft offers. They rebuilt the boot screen for you and you can use that. There is no known way of changing it currently, like we used to be able to do with XP and 7

To speed it up make sure you are using a real Class 10 SD card (do some speed tests make sure they meet the specifications)
Nothing much after that.. 2 minutes seems excessive. Mine boots in under 30 seconds with normal IoT on the latest Pi 3